# Getting NULL Pointer Exception

Tags: android, gridview, nullpointerexception

This is my ImageaAdapter Class

```
public class MyGeneralFragmentImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

   private Context mycontext;
   private LayoutInflater mInflater;

public Integer[] ImageIds = {
        R.drawable.world, R.drawable.us, 
        R.drawable.european_flag

};

public String[] Imagename = {
        "World","USA","Europe"

};

public MyGeneralFragmentImageAdapter(Context c){
    mycontext = c;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return ImageIds.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ViewHolder vh;

    if (convertView == null)
    {
    vh = new ViewHolder();
    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_grid,parent,false);
    vh.textview = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_text);
    vh.imageView = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_image);
    convertView.setTag(vh); 
    }
    else 
    { 
    vh = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();  
    }       

    //ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mycontext);
    vh.imageView.setImageResource(ImageIds[position]);
    vh.imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);


    vh.textview.setText(Imagename[position]);


    //imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(100, 100));


    return convertView;

}

static class ViewHolder
{
       TextView textview;
       ImageView imageView;
}

 }
```

This is my row_grid.xml

```
  <LinearLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:gravity="center_horizontal"
  >

 <Imageview 
   android:id="@+id/grid_item_image"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">
 </Imageview>

 <Textview
   android:id="@+id/grid_item_text"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:gravity="center_horizontal"
   android:text="TextView"
   android:textColor="#000000" />
```

I am getting Null Pointer Exception in this line

```
 convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_grid,parent,false);
```

Kindly help

**UPDATE**

I have changed the code and initialized layout inflatter.The code works fine but Its giving me Binary XML error

```
<Imageview 
   android:id="@+id/grid_item_image"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace your adapter constructor with this one:

```
public MyGeneralFragmentImageAdapter(Context c){
    mycontext = c;
    mInflator = LayoutInflater.from(c);
}
```

Comment: Its giving me Binary XML error
       <Imageview 
       android:id="@+id/grid_item_image"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content">
   </Imageview>

Answer (score 1):

You didn't initialize your `LayoutInflater`:

```
 LayoutInflater mInflater = (context).getLayoutInflater();
```

Comment: where should i initialize ?

Comment: you can initilize it in your If statement inside your getView function

Comment: and context is your Activity calling function,which you can pass it's context through this class Constructor

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to initialize your `LayoutInflator`

```
   mInflater = LayoutInflator.from(context);

   convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_grid,parent,false);
```

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
LayoutInflater mInflater

public MyGeneralFragmentImageAdapter(Context c){
mycontext = c;
mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(c);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just because mInflater have null value, So try this pass the Activity class in constructor

```
private LayoutInflater mInflater=null;

    public MyGeneralFragmentImageAdapter(Activity c){
        mInflater= c.getLayoutInflater();
    }
```

After that this is valid statement in getview

```
convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_grid,parent,false);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// try this way

convertView =LayoutInflater.from(mycontext).inflate(R.layout.row_grid,parent,false);
```

Comment: I am getting a Binary XML error in intializing the ImageView from row_grid.xml file